# How can i run macports and fink simultaneously on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, macports, fink

I have fink installed and working on my Catalina system.

I would like to also install macports to get some gtk3 software that fink doesn't seem to have.

How can i install macports in such a way that the two systems coexist harmoniously?

It's ok if there are duplicate packages, one living in /opt/sw and one living in /opt/local (or wherever macports puts its files).

I just don't want any mysterious failures of running or building software because of some interaction between the systems.

Comment: Just for reference, it looks like all you have to do is install fink using one user account and then install macports using another.  Then the two systems can exist side-by-side even if you install the same or similar packages in each.  And this is what i've done on my Catalina system.